# Show $[a]_m=[a]_n\cup[a+m]_n\cup\dots\cup[a+m(k-1)]_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $m|n$. Show that for any integer $a$ the congruence class $[a]_m$ is the union of congruences $[a]_n,[a+m]_n,[a+2m]_n,\dots,[a+n-m]_m$. Which is just showing $[a]_m=[a]_n\cup[a+m]_n\cup\dots\cup[a+n-m]_n$

> What I did first was let $mp=n$ where $p\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we can rewrite $[a]_m=[a]_n\cup[a+m]_n\cup\dots\cup[a+n-m]_n$  as $[a]_m=[a]_n\cup[a+m]_n\cup\dots\cup[a+m(p-1)]_n$ Now for proving this I tried proving $[a]_m\subseteq[a+sm]_n $ where $0\leq s \leq p-1$ and $s\in\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> Proof:
>   Let $t\in[a]_m$ $\implies t\equiv a\pmod{m}\implies t=a+mk'$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. By the divsion algorithm we have $k'=pq+r$ or  $r=k'-pq$ where $0\leq r<p$. Then $[t]_n=[a+k'm]_n=[a+(k'-pq)m]_n$ Thus $t\in[a+sm]_n$ since $0\leq k'-pq\leq p-1$ Do I have this direction correct?
>
> Now we show that $[a+sm]_n\subseteq [a]_m$ Let $k\in[a+sm]_n$.Then $k\equiv a+sm\pmod{n}\implies n|(k-a-sm)$ But since $m|n$ it follows that $m|(k-a-sm)$ Thus $mt'=k-a-sm$ where $t'\in\mathbb{Z}\implies mt'=(k-sm)-a$.Thus $k-sm\equiv a \pmod{m}$. Reducing this we get $k\equiv a+sm\pmod{m}$ $\equiv a\pmod{m}$. Thus $k\in[a]_m$. Thus  $[a+sm]_n\subseteq [a]_m$ 
>   Thus  $[a]_m=[a]_n\cup[a+m]_n\cup\dots\cup[a+n-m]_n$

Comment: I think it maybe wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by $[a]_m$? Is it the set of $k$ such that $k \equiv a (\mod m)$? Never mind - I see that this is indeed the definition from your proof.

Comment: yes. $a$ is just a arbitrary congruence class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks correct.

In the first part of the proof, it might be clearer to write $t\in[a+rm]_n$ where $0\le r\le p-1$ (instead of $t\in[a+sm]_n$ since $0\le k^{\prime}-pq\le p-1)$, although this is equivalent to what you have.

In the second part of the proof, I think you could shorten the argument by saying that if $k\equiv a+sm \pmod n$, then $k\equiv a+sm \equiv a \pmod m$, since $m|n$, so $k\in [a]_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I believe is your argument, but formatted so that it is a bit easier to read. You should check to see that it agrees with what you have written.

---

By definition,
$$
\begin{align}
x\in[a]_m&\iff\exists j\in\mathbb{Z}: x-a=jm\tag{1}\\[6pt]
m\mid n&\iff \exists k\in\mathbb{Z}: n=km\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
By the Division Algorithm, we must have $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $0\le r\lt k$ so that
$$
j=qk+r\tag{3}
$$
Then, by $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$,
$$
\begin{align}
x-a-rm
&=x-a-(j-qk)m\\
&=x-a-jm+qn\\
&=qn\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
x-a-rm=qn\iff x\in[a+rm]_n\tag{5}
$$
where $0\le r\lt k$. Thus, assuming $(2)$, $(1)\implies(5)$; that is,
$$
m\mid n\implies[a]_m\subset\bigcup_{r=0}^{k-1}[a+rm]_n\tag{6}
$$
Suppose $(2)$ and $(5)$. Then,
$$
x-a=rm+qn=(qk+r)m\iff x\in[a]_m\tag{7}
$$
Therefore, assuming $(2)$, $(5)\implies(7)$; that is,
$$
m\mid n\implies\bigcup_{r=0}^{k-1}[a+rm]_n\subset[a]_m\tag{8}
$$
Thus, $(6)$ and $(8)$ show that
$$
m\mid n\implies[a]_m=\bigcup_{r=0}^{k-1}[a+rm]_n\tag{9}
$$